# Passing an ArrayList of Object from one activity to another

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I'm trying to find a way to pass my already parsed JSON response from my API to another activity on a click event. When a user click on a preview, he gets redirected to the full article. Here I'm using an Adapter along with a DataClass

**User Feed**

```
  val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            { response ->
                Log.d("API Response", response.toString())
                val articlesArray = response.optJSONArray("articles")
                val newsList = parseNewsArticles(articlesArray)

                println(newsList)

                val newsAdapter = NewsAdapter(newsList as ArrayList<News>){
                    val myIntent = Intent(this@UserFeed, NewsDetails::class.java)
                    myIntent.putExtra("news", newsList)
                    startActivity(myIntent)
                }
                binding.recyclerView.adapter = newsAdapter
                binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@UserFeed)

            },
            { error ->
                Log.e("API Error", error.toString())
            })

        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
```

**Data Class**

```
data class News  (
    val author : String,
    val title : String,
    val url : String,
    val urlToImage : String,
    val description : String,
    val publishedAt : String,
    val content : String)
```

Finally I would like to be able to access the list as follow news.title on my NewsDetails Class Just like I do on my main Activity.

I aware of the possibility, but not ideal, to pass my JSON response inside my Intent and parse it again on my second Activity . I've also looked into serialize with getSerializable() but this will imply to cast my DataClass to serializable which will interfere with other parts of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to use `Parcelable` for sending list from one `Screen` to other via bundle/intent. You could also use `@Serializable` but given the implications on performance due to reflection better to stick with `Parcelable` and I do not see any implications on class being `Parcelable`

Add below to your plugins in `build.gradle` inside app module

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}
```

Then make data class parcelable

```
@Parcelize
data class News  (
    val author : String,
    val title : String,
    val url : String,
    val urlToImage : String,
    val description : String,
    val publishedAt : String,
    val content : String): Parcelable
```

while sending data

```
myIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("news", newsList)
startActivity(myIntent)
```

Comment: Hello Rajan, the plugin that you provide does not seem to be working

Comment: What is the problem? did you add `import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize` ?

Comment: refer this doc https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize

Comment: It is simply not syncing for me . I did take a look at the doc  but  id 'kotli... ' is not doing it for me. I'll keep on looking